# How to show MySQL data in graph?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, graph

I want to retrieve data from mysql in the form of graph with the following code. But, nothing is shown. Can anybody help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "graphdata.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
      }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      var options = {'title':'Ticket Sales','width':500,'height':400};

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data,options); 
  }
</script>
<?php
echo("<div id='chart_div'></div>");
?>
```

Here is my `getdata.php`:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(`booth_number`),`sold_by` FROM `registration1` where week(`Date`) =     week(curdate())  GROUP BY `sold_by`";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//start the json data in the format Google Chart js/API expects to recieve it
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Ticket Sales', 'type' => 'string')
      ),
    'rows' => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row[0]), array('v' => $row[1])));
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What is inside graphdata.php?

Comment: i attached the graphdata.php

Comment: Whenever you use `async: true` a kitten dies! Please use `$.ajax` properly, all you need is move your code into the `success()` callback (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information).

Comment: i remove the  async: true then the message shown:Table has no columns.

Comment: are u sure that ur calling the correct URL?? `graphdata.php` vs `getdata.php`

Comment: yes its graphdata not getdata

Comment: There's something missing in your second line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/`. Copy and paste or is that really missing in your page?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, I think you need to move your code inside the success callback:

```
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "graphdata.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(jsonData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            var options = {'title':'Ticket Sales','width':500,'height':400};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data,options); 
        }
    });
}
```

[edit] A working example (with some mocked data) can be found on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oCuBarI/latest).

[edit2] Update the example on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oCuBarI/5) with the output provided in the duplicate question:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {
            "label":"Month",
            "type":"string"
        },{
            "label":"Weekly Sales",
            "type":"string"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c":[
                {"v":"3"},
                {"v":"jaspreet singh "}
            ]
        },{
            "c":[
                {"v":"3"},
                {"v":"joseph swanson"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON returned by the server is wrong, the object should look like this:

```
  "cols": [
    {
      "label":"Month",
      "type":"string"
    },{
      "label":"Weekly Sales",
      "type":"number"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "c":[
        {"v":"jaspreet singh "},
        {"v":"3"}
      ]
    },{
      "c":[
        {"v":"joseph swanson"},
        {"v":"3"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

The changes needed should now be obvious. Hope this helps.

[edit3] `getdata.php` should contain the following snippet imho:

```
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Ticket Sales', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $data['rows'][] = array(
        'c' => array(
            array('v' => $row[1]),
            array('v' => $row[0])
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: @mamtasingla Do you get any output at all if you open the URL directly in the browser?

Comment: output : Table has no columns.

Comment: @mamtasingla Sounds like there's your problem, doesn't it? Open a new question if you need help with that problem as well.

Comment: my example shows that the suggested changes with. from your error message i'd say that the returned json is wrongly formatted. change your output with the mock on jsbin, debug there and then fix ur php code.

Comment: @nietonfir: a new question has been asked, but it ends up looking like a duplicate, even though it is slightly different. Thus, I think a new question may have been redundant here (I initially voted to put on hold, but have now retracted).

Comment: @halfer you're right, 2nd question as it stands should be added here and closed as a duplicate. My intention was to have him ask specifically for the google graph error message.

Comment: @mamtasingla Update my answer, got a working example with your JSON. The necessary changes should now be easy.